# How do I reorder the pages opened on startup Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ordering

I've got a number of pages set to open when I start Google Chrome (1), but I'd like to change their order. There's no option on the **Options** dialog **Basics** tab for reordering the pages (2):

[image]

Where does Chrome store this information so I can reorder the tabs without having to remove and readd tabs.

The fall back is to set up the tabs I want in the correct order, remove **all** the existing ones and then click on "Use Current".

Comment: I changed the tab order in Preferences file present in `Appdata\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`, and it worked for the first time, but the changes were rolled back once I closed and started a new browser session. Will check further. @ChrisF

Comment: @Sathya - I was looking in the registry, which is why I didn't find anything. I'll investigate this myself as well.

Comment: About your fallback: It looks like the "Use Current" button replaces everything, so you don't have to bother with Removing everything first. So your fallback could be: Open just one Chrome so your homepage tabs appear, re-order them the way you want, then go to the Options and click "Use Current".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the "Use Current" button replaces everything, so you don't have to bother with Removing everything first. So as an alternative, you can open just one Chrome so your homepage tabs appear, re-order them the way you want, then go to the Options and click "Use Current".

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed. With newer Chrome versions you can re-order startup tabs using drag-and-drop.

**Step 1**

Open Chrome, click on "Customize and control Google Chrome" in top-right corner, and select Settings.

[image]

**Step 2**

Under *Settings » On Startup » Open a specific page or set of pages*, you can add and remove pages, or drag the handle to change their order.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This no longer works and probably hasn't for a long time.

I am using the latest chrome 103.0.5060.66 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and there is no handle to drag anywhere.

The only way i have found to re-order tabs is to close chrome, let it open m7y default tabs, open the tab I want to add and put it where I want it, then save startup pages again.